# IntelliJ warning about unresolved variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to load game from local storage and I am getting weird warning. It works, but I like my code clean.

```
var save = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('save000'));
var playerLocation = save[1].playerLocation;
```

<kbd>.playerlocation</kbd> is underlined and I see warning <kbd>unresolved variable playerLocation</kbd>

This question is not a duplicate because save variable is not declared in the function signature, but is generated based on local storage. I can only declare JSDoc variables that are declared in the function signature.

Comment: You should probably clean up your tags, I think it's either `phpstorm` or `intellij` but not both (if any).

Comment: I guess the second one is underlined ? Does it works if you do : `var playerLocation = save[1]['playerLocation'];` that should resolve your issue ?

Comment: Not sure if the dupe "makes code clean", but it at least changes it from "orange" to "a lot of unnecessary annotations" :)

Comment: @fvu - PHPstorm is just Intellij with php plugins.

Comment: @Sylvain Attoumani - it works, thank you :)

Comment: @JonasWilms the duplicate doesn't solve my problem - it gives me other warnings as var 'save' would have to be declared in the function signature. I could split it into multiple functions, but Sylvain Attoumani already gave me working answer that is a lot less intrusive.

Comment: Have a look at the third answer or so, that also explains how to annotate variables inside functions

Comment: @JonasWilms ok, you're right, that one works, thank you. Still like the other way though.

Comment: Well the "other way" would be to adopt a less readable identical syntax just to make the IDE happy, most other linters will highlight it the other way round.